# Adding a theme attribute to managed_file field, remove button reloads the page in drupal 7 form

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, drupal-forms, managed-file

I am using Drupal 7 for a form. In the form I have a managed_file field. When I **add theme attribute** to the managed_file field, the **remove button reloads the page** on removing the image. The upload works fine. 
Prior adding the theme attribute the remove button was working fine as well. 
Here is my managed_file field.

```
$form['profile_image'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Profile Image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#default_value' => profile_image['user']->field_profile_image['und']['0']['fid'],
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#theme' => 'module_upload_thumb_style',
);
```

Here is the theme function that I am using to style the uploaded image instead of showing just the name of the image.

```
function theme_module_upload_thumb_style($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    if (isset($element['#file']->uri)) {
        $output = '<div id="edit-logo-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-logo"><span class="file">';
        $output .= '<img height="50px" src="' . image_style_url('thumbnail', $element['#file']->uri) . '" />';
        $output .= '</span><input style="margin-left:20px;" type="submit" id="edit-' . $element['#name'] . '-remove-button" name="' . $element['#name'] . '_remove_button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary ajax-processed">';
        $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $element['#name'] . '[fid]" value="' . $element['#file']->fid . '"></div></div>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

When **commenting the theme** attribute in the form field, the remove button removes the image **without refreshing the page**. But on **adding the theme** attribute,
the functionality remains the same but **with page reload**

Answer (score 0):

After digging some more into the issue, I found a relevant solution to the problem. 
After updating the theme function to as below, the remove button works like a charm.
Here is the updated function:

```
function theme_module_upload_thumb_style($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $attributes = array();
    if (isset($element['#id'])) {
        $attributes['id'] = $element['#id'];
    }
    if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
        $attributes['class'] = (array) $element['#attributes']['class'];
    }
    $attributes['class'][] = 'form-managed-file';
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';
    if (isset($element['#file']->uri)) {
        $output .= '<img src="' . image_style_url('thumbnail', $element['#file']->uri) . '" />';
    }
    $output .= drupal_render_children($element);
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```